# Subquery returns more than row

Tags: mysql

Suppose I had two tables, **t_employee** and **t_leave**.

I would like to print **employeeName** & **substituteEmployeeName**.

In the **t_employee** table, there is **id** of employee and **name** of the employee.

In the **t_leave**, there is **id** of t_leave, **employee_id** & **substitute_id**.

I have tried this code but it will not work.

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT t_employee.name FROM t_employee JOIN t_leave WHERE temployee.id=t_leave.substitute_id)
FROM t_leave JOIN t_employee
WHERE t_employee.id=t_leave.employee.id
```

Can someone help me ?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You have to LImit it to one, or use Aggregation function LIKE MAX or MIN

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT t_employee.name FROM t_employee JOIN t_leave WHERE temployee.id=t_leave.substitute_id ORDER BY t_employee.name LIMIT 1 )
FROM t_leave JOIN t_employee
WHERE t_employee.id=t_leave.employee.id
```